# typescript - namespace problem not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, namespaces

this is my client class:

```js
namespace Core {
    export class Client {}
}
```

and I create a new object like below:

```js
let client = new Core.Client();
```

but I get this error:

```
/dist/index.js:10
    let client = new Core.Client()
                 ^

ReferenceError: Core is not defined
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (/dist/index.js:10:18)
    at Namespace.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Namespace.emit (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:213:10)
    at /node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:181:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your namespace in your `index.ts`. So if `Client` is in a file called `core.ts` you need to do:

```
/// <reference path="core.ts" />
let client = new Core.Client();
```

And you need to export your namespace:

```
export namespace Core {
    export class Client {}
}
```

See the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files) for more information.